# Blank Page issue with React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a React.js script in Visual Studio. When I try to run my code using "npm run dev" on a local server, I'm getting a blank webpage but no errors are shown, Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

What confuses me is that it was working 2 days ago and I haven't made any changes.

Here's some of script for context;

App.jsx

```
import { Navbar, Welcome, Footer, Services, Transactions } from "./components";

const App = () => (
  <div className="min-h-screen">
    <div className="gradient-bg-welcome">
      <Navbar />
      <Welcome />
    </div>
    <Services />
    <Transactions />
    <Footer />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

main.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx';
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

index.js

```
export { default as Loader } from './Loader';
export { default as Footer } from './Footer';
export { default as Navbar } from './Navbar';
export { default as Services } from './Services';
export { default as Transactions } from './Transactions';
export { default as Welcome } from './Welcome';
```

index.css

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap");

* html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.gradient-bg-welcome {
  background-color:#0f0e13;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(at 0% 0%, hsla(253,16%,7%,1) 0, transparent 50%), 
    radial-gradient(at 50% 0%, hsla(225,39%,30%,1) 0, transparent 50%), 
    radial-gradient(at 100% 0%, hsla(339,49%,30%,1) 0, transparent 50%);
}

.gradient-bg-services {
  background-color:#0f0e13;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(at 0% 0%, hsla(253,16%,7%,1) 0, transparent 50%), 
    radial-gradient(at 50% 100%, hsla(225,39%,25%,1) 0, transparent 50%);
}

.gradient-bg-transactions {
  background-color: #0f0e13;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(at 0% 100%, hsla(253,16%,7%,1) 0, transparent 50%), 
    radial-gradient(at 50% 0%, hsla(225,39%,25%,1) 0, transparent 50%);
}

.gradient-bg-footer {
  background-color: #0f0e13;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(at 0% 100%, hsla(253,16%,7%,1) 0, transparent 53%), 
    radial-gradient(at 50% 150%, hsla(339,49%,30%,1) 0, transparent 50%);
}

.blue-glassmorphism {
  background: rgb(39, 51, 89, 0.4);
  border-radius: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

/* white glassmorphism */
.white-glassmorphism {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
  border-radius: 16px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.eth-card {
  background-color:#a099ff;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(at 83% 67%, rgb(152, 231, 156) 0, transparent 58%), 
    radial-gradient(at 67% 20%, hsla(357,94%,71%,1) 0, transparent 59%), 
    radial-gradient(at 88% 35%, hsla(222,81%,65%,1) 0, transparent 50%), 
    radial-gradient(at 31% 91%, hsla(9,61%,61%,1) 0, transparent 52%), 
    radial-gradient(at 27% 71%, hsla(336,91%,65%,1) 0, transparent 49%), 
    radial-gradient(at 74% 89%, hsla(30,98%,65%,1) 0, transparent 51%), 
    radial-gradient(at 53% 75%, hsla(174,94%,68%,1) 0, transparent 45%);
}

.text-gradient {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(at 4% 36%, hsla(0,0%,100%,1) 0, transparent 53%), radial-gradient(at 100% 60%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 0, transparent 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
}

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Welcome.jsx

```
import { AiFillPlayCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
import { SiEthereum } from "react-icons/si";
import { BsInfoCircle } from "react-icons/bs";

import { Loader } from ".";

const companyCommonStyles = "min-h-[70px] sm:px-0 px-2 sm:min-w-[120px] flex justify-center items-center border-[0.5px] border-gray-400 text-sm font-light text-white";

const Input = ({ placeholder, name, type, value, handleChange }) => (
  <input
    placeholder={placeholder}
    type={type}
    step="0.0001"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, name)}
    className="my-2 w-full rounded-sm p-2 outline-none bg-transparent text-white border-none text-sm white-glassmorphism"
  />
);

const Welcome = () => {
  const connectWallet = () => {};

  return (
    <div className="flex w-full justify-center items-center">
      <div className="flex mf:flex-row flex-col items-start justify-between md:p-20 py-12 px-4">
        <div className="flex flex-1 justify-start items-start flex-col mf:mr-10">
          <h1 className="text-3xl sm:text-5xl text-white text-gradient py-1">
            Send Crypto <br /> across the world
          </h1>
          <p className="text-left mt-5 text-white font-light md:w-9/12 w-11/12 text-base">
            Explore the crypto world. Buy and sell cryptocurrencies easily on Krypt.
          </p>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={connectWallet}
            className="flex flex-row justify-center items-center my-5 bg-[#2952e3] p-3 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#2546bd]"
          >
            <AiFillPlayCircle className="text-white mr-2" />
            <p className="text-white text-base font-semibold">
              Connect Wallet
            </p>
          </button>

          <div className="grid sm:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-2 w-full mt-10">
            <div className={`rounded-tl-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Reliability
            </div>
            <div className={companyCommonStyles}>Security</div>
            <div className={`sm:rounded-tr-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Ethereum
            </div>
            <div className={`sm:rounded-bl-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Web 3.0
            </div>
            <div className={companyCommonStyles}>Low Fees</div>
            <div className={`rounded-br-2xl ${companyCommonStyles}`}>
              Blockchain
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col flex-1 items-center justify-end w-full mf:mt-0 mt-10">
          <div className="p-3 flex justify-end items-start flex-col rounded-xl h-40 sm:w-72 w-full my-5 eth-card white-glassmorphism">
            <div className="flex justify-between w-full items-center mb-2">
              <div className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full border-2 border-white flex justify-center items-center">
                <SiEthereum fontSize={21} color="#fff" />
              </div>
              <BsInfoCircle fontSize={17} color="#fff" />
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full h-full">
              <p className="text-white font-light text-sm mb-1">Address</p>
              <p className="text-white font-semibold text-lg mt-1">
                Ethereum
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="p-5 sm:w-96 w-full flex flex-col justify-start items-center blue-glassmorphism">
            <Input placeholder="Address To" name="addressTo" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Amount (ETH)" name="amount" type="number" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Keyword (Gif)" name="keyword" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
            <Input placeholder="Enter Message" name="message" type="text" handleChange={handleChange} />
          
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the console output enabling chrome developer tools. What output is showing?

Comment: Okay thanks, the console shows the following errors;

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_updatedFibers')
    at requestUpdateLane (react-dom.development.js:25416:23)
    at updateContainer (react-dom.development.js:28815:14)
    at ReactDOMHydrationRoot.render.ReactDOMRoot.render (react-dom.development.js:29314:3)
    at main.tsx:6:69

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Can anyone help with these errors?

Comment: Try to comment this line in webpack.config.js:
`
// 'react-dom': '@hot-loader/react-dom',
`

Comment: Sorry I don't have a webpackconfig.js, I have a postcss.config.js Or a tailwind.config.js